# How to pass object to child component via Inputs() but never update input when it changes in parent

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm passing an object from a parent component to a child component via Inputs(). I know because I'm passing an object and not a primitive type it's passing a reference to the object. Thus when the object changes in the parent I see it being reflected in the child.

What is the optimal way to pass an object via Inputs() that does NOT update the child component when it changes in the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two properties that you use. One that you modify and a second that is passed to the child component but is a clone of the original.

```
 @Component({..})
 export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
     // the original object value
     public value: any;
     // a value used by child components
     public forChild: any;

     public OnInit() {
         // use deconstruction to make a copy
         this.forChild = {...this.value};
         // use assign to make a copy
         this.forChild = Object.assign({}, this.value);
         // use JSON to make a deep copy
         this.forChild = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.value));
     }
 }
```

Comment: BOOM! Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned: 
When we pass objects using @Input(), it would be passed as a reference,
and  When we pass primitive types, it would be passed as a value.

So i think one solution is to convert your object to string, and then pass it using @Input(). Later you can decode this stringifyed object to a object if you need.